# How to reorder li element only on mobile view using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to reorder li element only on mobile view not on desktop view using JavaScript or jQuery? Here the code and image for reference.

Any help is massively appreciated!.

```html
<ul class="kt-tabs-title-list kb-tabs-list-columns kb-tab-title-columns-8" role="tablist">
  <li id="tab-pastries" class="kt-title-item kt-title-item-1 kt-tabs-svg-show-always kt-tabs-icon-side-right kt-tab-title-active" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-pastries" data-tab="1" class="kt-tab-title kt-tab-title-1 " role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0"><span class="kt-title-text">Pastries</span></a></li>
  <li id="tab-brownies" class="kt-title-item kt-title-item-2 kt-tabs-svg-show-always kt-tabs-icon-side-right kt-tab-title-inactive" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-brownies" data-tab="2" class="kt-tab-title kt-tab-title-2 " role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="kt-title-text">Brownies</span></a></li>
  <li id="tab-cakes" class="kt-title-item kt-title-item-3 kt-tabs-svg-show-always kt-tabs-icon-side-right kt-tab-title-inactive" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-cakes" data-tab="3" class="kt-tab-title kt-tab-title-3 " role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="kt-title-text">Cakes</span></a></li>
  <li id="tab-cookies" class="kt-title-item kt-title-item-4 kt-tabs-svg-show-always kt-tabs-icon-side-right kt-tab-title-inactive" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-cookies" data-tab="4" class="kt-tab-title kt-tab-title-4 " role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="kt-title-text">Cookies</span></a></li>
  <li id="tab-breads" class="kt-title-item kt-title-item-5 kt-tabs-svg-show-always kt-tabs-icon-side-right kt-tab-title-inactive" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-breads" data-tab="5" class="kt-tab-title kt-tab-title-5 " role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="kt-title-text">Breads</span></a></li>
  <li id="tab-sugarfree" class="kt-title-item kt-title-item-6 kt-tabs-svg-show-always kt-tabs-icon-side-right kt-tab-title-inactive" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-sugarfree" data-tab="6" class="kt-tab-title kt-tab-title-6 " role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="kt-title-text">Sugar Free</span></a></li>
  <li id="tab-bestsellers" class="kt-title-item kt-title-item-7 kt-tabs-svg-show-always kt-tabs-icon-side-right kt-tab-title-inactive" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-bestsellers" data-tab="7" class="kt-tab-title kt-tab-title-7 " role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="kt-title-text">Best Sellers</span></a></li>
  <li id="tab-onsales" class="kt-title-item kt-title-item-8 kt-tabs-svg-show-always kt-tabs-icon-side-right kt-tab-title-inactive" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-onsales" data-tab="8" class="kt-tab-title kt-tab-title-8 " role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="kt-title-text">On Sales %</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

The order view tabs in desktop is remain :

[image]

Only in mobile view, reorder from this :

[image]

to this :

[image]

Comment: I must ask, why would you do this?

Answer (score 3):

You could add two lists, one for desktop and one for mobile with the classes `desktop-view` and `mobile-view` and then use media querys in your css to switch visibility of both classes

```
.mobile-view{visibility:hidden}
.desktop-view{visibility:hidden}

// For Mobile Screens
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .mobile-view{visibility:visible}
}

// For Bigger Screens (600px+ is tablets, 768px+ is Desktop)
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .desktop-view{visibility:visible}
}
```